# Grepping the line from log file and based on that line printing the pass or fail

Tags: perl, shell

I am writing one perl script where in I have to grep the particular line or string or text from log file which is present in the remote machine which is connected using "Expect" module from my perl script. And, if that line is present in the file then I have to print the output pass or fail.

Hope this is clear,

Below is code I am trying out:

```
$var1->send("grep Expected sea*\n");
```

Grepping the "Expected sea*" from log file. How to pass this line or string to variable and how to print it pass or fail.

Comment: What class is `$var1` blessed to?

Comment: I am trying to use Expect module of perl

Answer (score 0):

`Send` will echo the output to the pty, if you are trying to capture the output after your command execution then you need to use exp_after.

```
     An example say:
      my $cmd = "your grep cmd";
      my $output;
     [
        qr"yourhostname",
        sub {
        $spawn_ok =1;
        my $val1 = shift; 
        $var1->send("$cmd; exit \n");
        exp_continue;
        }
     ],
     [
       qr"Expected sea*",  #you can match some string 
       sub {
            my $val1 = shift;
            $output = $val1->exp_after; #output of grep
            exp_continue;
            }
      ],

      print $output; # from here you can use $output to parse and with if condition you can print yes or no
```

This is the closed I've tried.. hope this helps also you can check [cpan] (http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod "Expect")